# Echo / printr inside variable

Tags: php

I have inside a php file a variable called $html which is gathering lots of information like this:

```
$html .= something;
$html .= something else;
etc
```

and in another file its being echoed like this:

```
echo $this->html;
```

What i need is at first file that $html .= is used to echo something like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo 'printr($this->cart)';
echo '</pre>';
```

But i need those 3 lines to be included in $html variable in order to be echoed at second file through: echo $this->html;

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What? Your question is incredible confusing, what is the issue / what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

use `var_export()` function for including your array in to `$html` variable

Answer (score 0):

In php file just assign what you want to assign to $html variable then you can print it anywhere by it's variable name .

for example : 
`$html="";`
`$html .="your text";`
`$html .="any dynamic values";`

then echo this like
`echo $html;`

if you are using function then simply call a function and pass your all code within function then called function from anywhere.